# lxml only loading a single network entity before raising XMLSyntaxError

Tags: python, lxml

I am writing code to work with Amazon query based APIs, which return XML which I then wish to parse with lxml. I have written several functions which work perfectly to load the XML and parse it.

Each function loads the XML using:

```
variable = lxml.etree.parse("http://...")
```

This works perfectly, the FIRST time it is run. However, if I wish to load a second URL (be it the same one, or a different one) during the course of a running python session, I get the error:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Attempt to load network entity http://...
```

(Of course, the ellipses are replaced in both cases with the rest of the URL.)

Therefore, for some reason, I appear to be unable to load two XML documents using the parse method in a running python session.

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong here, or have a solution?

Comment: It will be helpful. If we could know which version of python you are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Known unfixed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/673205).

Use `urllib2.urlopen()` to get a file-like object and pass that to `lxml.etree.parse()`

Comment: You can also make a parser with `no_network` set to `False`: `p = etree.XMLParser(no_network=False)` and then use it with `etree.parse(uri, parser=p)` or set it as the default parser with `etree.set_default_parser(p)` (possible downside might be unexpected network access for "secondary" resources, like dtd's etc...)